# Bxslider not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, bxslider

I'm implementing bxSlider in a rails app, I'm having trouble making it work, so far my issue is transition is not working instead appear each one below the other. Can you point me what I'm missing?

HTML:

```
  <!--BxSlider-->
    <ul class="bxslider">
      <li>
        <%= image_tag "header1.png" %>
        <div class="row text-center">
          <div class="span10 offset1">
          <h1>Tittle one</h1><br />
          <a class="btn-main" href="about.html">Learn More</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <%= image_tag "header2.png" %>
        <div class="row text-center">
          <div class="span10 offset1">
          <h1>Tittle 2</h1><br />
          <a class="btn-main" href="about.html">Learn More</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

CSS:

```
/** RESET AND LAYOUT
===================================*/

.bx-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto 60px;
    padding: 0;
    *zoom: 1;
}

.bx-wrapper img {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

/** THEME
===================================*/

.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
    border: solid #fff 5px;
    left: -5px;
    background: #fff;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -30px;
    width: 100%;
}

/* LOADER */

.bx-wrapper .bx-loading {
    min-height: 50px;
    background: url(bx_loader.gif) center center no-repeat #fff;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2000;
}

/* PAGER */

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: .85em;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #666;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager .bx-pager-item,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-controls-auto-item {
    display: inline-block;
    *zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a {
    background: #666;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    display: block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    outline: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a:hover,
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a.active {
    background: #000;
}

/* DIRECTION CONTROLS (NEXT / PREV) */

.bx-wrapper .bx-prev {
    left: 10px;
    background: url(controls.png) no-repeat 0 -32px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-next {
    right: 10px;
    background: url(controls.png) no-repeat -43px -32px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-prev:hover {
    background-position: 0 0;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-next:hover {
    background-position: -43px 0;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-direction a {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -16px;
    outline: 0;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-direction a.disabled {
    display: none;
}

/* AUTO CONTROLS (START / STOP) */

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto {
    text-align: center;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-start {
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 11px;
    outline: 0;
    background: url(controls.png) -86px -11px no-repeat;
    margin: 0 3px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-start:hover,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-start.active {
    background-position: -86px 0;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-stop {
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 9px;
    height: 11px;
    outline: 0;
    background: url(controls.png) -86px -44px no-repeat;
    margin: 0 3px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-stop:hover,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-stop.active {
    background-position: -86px -33px;
}

/* PAGER WITH AUTO-CONTROLS HYBRID LAYOUT */

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls.bx-has-controls-auto.bx-has-pager .bx-pager {
    text-align: left;
    width: 80%;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls.bx-has-controls-auto.bx-has-pager .bx-controls-auto {
    right: 0;
    width: 35px;
}

/* IMAGE CAPTIONS */

.bx-wrapper .bx-caption {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #666\9;
    background: rgba(80, 80, 80, 0.75);
    width: 100%;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-caption span {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Arial;
    display: block;
    font-size: .85em;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

JS:

```
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            mode: 'fade',
            auto: true,
            pause: 4000,
            autoHover: false,
            touchEnabled: true,
            adaptiveHeight: false,
            autoControls: false
          }); 
  });
  </script>
```

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'bxSlider'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you had an issue where you were not referencing the correct library for Bxslider.

I pasted your code in a fiddle. Made couple of changes in HTML(img tags) as it was ruby-on-rails code pasted the CSS and Jquery. Presto it worked. Check it out.

[Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/uRzFk/)

HTML

```
  <ul class="bxslider">
      <li>
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports" />
        <div class="row text-center">
          <div class="span10 offset1">
          <h1>Tittle one:Sports</h1><br />
          <a class="btn-main" href="about.html">Learn More</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals" />
        <div class="row text-center">
          <div class="span10 offset1">
          <h1>Tittle 2:Animals</h1><br />
          <a class="btn-main" href="about.html">Learn More</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
```